# Request to a multi-page address that changes pages without changing the url

Tags: python, api, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

I want to request this url:

https://www.codal.ir/CompanyList.aspx

[image: A screenshot of the page]

This url contains tables on 110 pages that when the page is changed, neither the url nor the new request is changed.

this is my code:

```
import requests as req
req = req.Session()
isics = req.get("https://www.codal.ir/CompanyList.aspx")
print(isics.text)
```

but I only get the first page information.I intend to extract the required information from the tables by request and regex but if you have another way I will be happy to hear .Thanks for helping me get the whole pages.

Comment: I'll prepare an answer but I have to know if you can use ```Selenium```. I'll use it to automate navigation between the pages.

Comment: Yes I can use. I was looking for a way to use the request library to be faster, but I would be happy if you solve the problem with selenium as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Selenium` to navigate in the table. You can't do that with `requests`, because we do not have links that redirect us to the new page in the table. You can find the code below.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_company_links(links, driver):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    rows = soup.select("table.companies-table tr")
    for row in rows:
        link = row.select_one("a")
        if(link): 
            links.append("https://www.codal.ir/" + link['href'])



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.codal.ir/CompanyList.aspx")

current_page_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"].normal.selected')
page_number = int(current_page_button.get_attribute('value'))

while(True):
    get_company_links(links, driver)
    next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucPager1_btnNext')
    next_page_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    previous_page_number = page_number
    current_page_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"].normal.selected')
    page_number = int(current_page_button.get_attribute('value'))
    if(previous_page_number == page_number):
        break  # no more page left 

print(links)
```

Main working principle is navigating through the table and collecting links of the company websites. We use `next` button to navigate and stop when last page index is equal to the current index, which indicates that we arrived at the end of the table.

Comment: Thanks @Muhteva  , yes, it was useful for solving the problem and shortened the solution, I just made small changes, set up the webdriver for Firefox, put the "rows" information for each page in a string, and easily extracted the information I wanted with regex.

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful.